# Efficient method of removing duplicacy in Lists in GAP

Tags: group-theory, gap

Suppose that in GAP, a list is made up of certain conjugacy classes of a group $G$. Now, the list can contain same conjugacy class more than once, that is, there can be duplicacy. A standard method to remove duplicacy as far as I know is to write $S:=Set(K);$, where $K$ is our given list.

Is there any other efficient way to do this. A reason to ask this is if the conjugacy classes in the list $K$ are really large in size then the command $Set(K)$ , I suspect is not much efficient!

Thanks in advance for any kind of help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Set` will also aim to arrane in an (induced) total ordering, which can be expensive to compute. `Unique` removes duplicates without trying to sort, and is probably what you want to use